# Why is my universal selector overriding my element selector?

Tags: css

Apologies if this has been asked, but I can't figure out why this is happening! The text is appearing as **black**, even though I've set it up in the body selector as **red**. I appreciate the help.
(Note: The same thing happens with the div selector)

css:

```
* {
  color: black;
}

body {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <body>
    <h2>Hi!</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus,
      reprehenderit expedita, non eveniet qui eos nostrum, tenetur odit
      perferendis praesentium voluptatem nobis rerum laborum. Nobis consequuntur
      reprehenderit id nesciunt exercitationem!
    </p>
  </body>
```

Comment: Because `* { ... }` in this specific case is (essentially) the equivalent of  `body, h2, p{ color: black }`. Your paragraph isn't going to inherit the colour of your body, because you have explicitely given it the `color` property.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but isn't the universal selector supposed to have the least specificity? And why does it also override my div selector?

Comment: This isn't a matter of specificity. You are targeting `body` and only `body` with your second block; you're only applying one style to your paragraph. Your paragraph would take on the colour had you not used `* {  }` due to *inheritence*, not specificity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body doesn't contain any text directly. That is why you can't see the red text. While `*` applies to all the selectors, hence you can only see the black color.

Look at the following code, it will make more sense to you.

```css
*{
  color: black;
}

body {
  color: green;
}

p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
   Body text
    <h2>Hi!</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus,
      reprehenderit expedita, non eveniet qui eos nostrum, tenetur odit
      perferendis praesentium voluptatem nobis rerum laborum. Nobis consequuntur
      reprehenderit id nesciunt exercitationem!
    </p>
  </body>
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot!! Now I get it. The universal selector targets all elements. The body selector didn't affect the heading and paragraph because it was directly targeted by the universal selector. This would be different if the text was directly in the body, which will be affected by the body selector because it has more specificity. 
Again, thanks a lot for the answer!!!

Comment: Exactly! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to target the paragraph and the heading (p/h2)

The `*` applies to all selectors but CSS is cascading as the name explains which means that any style you give to a div below the first rule, will override whatever you have on the `*`

Give them a class attribute

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <h2 class="heading">Hi!</h2>
  <p class="paragraph">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus,
    reprehenderit expedita, non eveniet qui eos nostrum, tenetur odit
    perferendis praesentium voluptatem nobis rerum laborum. Nobis consequuntur
    reprehenderit id nesciunt exercitationem!
  </p>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  color: black;
}

.heading, .paragraph {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: red;
}
```